# SQLAlchemy (sql) conditional query

Tags: python, mysql, sql, sqlalchemy

I have this problem, I have a table `product` like this with two columns `target` and `actual`, how can I build a query and tell it : `if target == '' then select from actual`. To be clearer, this is my table `product` with the two columns :

```
actual | target
---------------
  p12  | <null>
  p14  | h20
  p16  | <null>
  p16  | <null>
  p16  | <null>
  p16  | <null>
  p16  | <null>
```

So I would like to select for example a value 'xx', how can I build this condition in SQLAlchemy (or sql) telling it to look for it in column `target` but if the cell is empty (is null) then look for it inside the `actual` column cell.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

sounds like you want `COALESCE()`, which takes several arguments and returns the first which is not null (or null if all args are null)

Presuming a reasonable setup:

```
import sqlalchemy as sa
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

Base = declarative_base()

class Product(Base):
    __tablename__ = "product"
    id = sa.Column(sa.Integer, primary_key=True)
    actual = sa.Column(sa.String)
    target = sa.Column(sa.String)
```

use `sqlalchemy.func.coalesce()`:

```
>>> print session.query(sa.func.coalesce(Product.target, Product.actual).label('x'))
SELECT coalesce(product.target, product.actual) AS x 
FROM product
>>> session.query(sa.func.coalesce(Product.target, Product.actual).label('x')).all()
[(u'p12'), (u'h20'), (u'p16'), (u'p16'), (u'p16'), (u'p16'), (u'p16')]
```

---

edit: if your missing values are not null, but some other value, you should use a `CASE` expression.

```
>>> print session.query(sa.case([(Product.target == '', Product.actual)], else_=Product.target))
SELECT CASE WHEN (product.target = :target_1) THEN product.actual ELSE product.target END AS anon_1 
FROM product
```

Comment: one question please, is there a function that does the same but with `empty` values (value = '')?

Answer (score 0):

use `IFNULL(Target,Actual)` instead of `Target`

ISnull is SQL, ifnull is mysql, sorry about that.

Comment: ISNULL() takes only one parameter, did you IFNULL()?

Answer (score 0):

SQL has a case statement. In this case it would be something like:

CASE MYTARGET WHEN TARGET IS NOT NULL THEN TARGET ELSE ACTUAL

I am not a db expert but I have used this construct. Mytarget is a new column